# how can i found where define a div in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, function

recently I install a new template on my new WordPress weblog
but the designer of template add a footer copyright that I can't delete it and I think he's done that with a function as I search all PHP and CSS file for the text he uses but it's not found.
also, I search with inspect element for that and know he uses 2 copyright div but set one of the display: none (original) and set one other to inline-block.

I remove attribute that he used for styling that div but after refresh the website it's back

I think he uses a function to do that but I can't find that.

for more info please look at the screenshots below

https://expressimg.com/images/2018/04/02/01.png

http://expressimg.com/images/2018/04/02/0151bba.png

and please visit my weblog and check it yourself https://asterixarts.com

Comment: Set `.site-info{ display: none !important}`

Comment: @LuísP.A.I do that but it's not work

Comment: very strange ... that code do the job, and there is no inline code. set the code at the end of the css, and be sure that is the last css reading

Comment: @LuísP.A. thanks, it works fine right now, but the cause it's not working is CloudFlare cache system. I purge everything and test it again and now it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can target his copyright container with CSS and apply "display:none !important;" to it. So no matter how he's adding it, (with JS or a PHP function) it won't display.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick div name an file search with that div name to Wordpress folder